# Hotel availability search query on MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am just having a little problem for calculating the total price of each room by hotel.

For example:

ROOM_1_TOTAL would be 170 on each row where Hotel_ID is 1.
ROOM_2_TOTAL would be 170 on each row where Hotel_ID is 1.

ROOM_1_TOTAL would be 10 on each row where Hotel_ID is 2.(I m sure, it is not working)
ROOM_2_TOTAL would be 10 on each row where Hotel_ID is 2.(For sure, it is not working)

And so on...

Here is my code along with output..

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/575d3/2

MYSQL QUERY:

DB Structure and dummy data...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `omc_hotel` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `omc_hotel` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Hotel ABC'),
(2, 'Hotel CSB'),
(3, 'Hotel CSD'),
(4, 'Hotel NDG');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `omc_hotel_room` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `pax_min` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pax_max` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `hotel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
INSERT INTO `omc_hotel_room` (`id`, `name`, `pax_min`,  `pax_max`, `quantity`, `hotel_id`) VALUES
(1,'Single',1,1,150,1),
(2,'Single',1,1,250,2),
(3,'Double',2,2,200,1),
(4,'Double',2,2,405,2),
(5,'Double',1,1,405,3),
(6,'Double Delax',2,2,50,3),
(7,'Double',1,1,100,4);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `omc_hotel_room_extra_quota` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hotel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `room_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `omc_hotel_room_extra_quota` (`id`, `hotel_id`, `room_type_id`, `quantity`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, -10, '2013-08-13'),
(2, 1, 3, -10, '2013-08-25'),
(3, 2, 2, 0, '2013-09-26'),
(4, 2, 4, 0, '2013-09-27'),
(5, 3, 5, 0, '2013-10-28'),
(6, 3, 5, 0, '2013-10-09');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `omc_hotel_room_pricelist` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hotel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `room_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `season_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price_normal` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci;

INSERT INTO `omc_hotel_room_pricelist` (`id`, `hotel_id`, `room_type_id`, `season_id`, `price_normal`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1, 50.00),
(2, 2, 2, 2, 10.00),
(3, 1, 1, 1, 35.00),
(4, 1, 1, 2, 70.00),
(5, 1, 1, 1, 80.00),
(6, 2, 4, 1, 80.00),
(7, 4, 7, 2, 80.00),
(8, 3, 6, 1, 80.00),
(9, 3, 5, 1, 30.00);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `omc_hotel_season_period` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hotel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `season_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci;


INSERT INTO `omc_hotel_season_period` (`id`, `hotel_id`, `season_id`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, '2013-08-13'),
(2, 1, 1, '2013-08-14'),
(3, 1, 2, '2013-08-15'),
(4, 2, 1, '2013-08-13'),
(5, 2, 1, '2013-08-14'),
(6, 2, 2, '2013-08-15'),
(7, 3, 2, '2013-08-13'),
(8, 3, 2, '2013-08-14'),
(9, 3, 1, '2013-08-15'),
(10, 1, 1, '2013-08-13'),
(11, 1, 1, '2013-08-14'),
(12, 1, 1, '2013-08-14');

SELECT candidates.hotel_id, omc_hotel_season_period.season_id,
       room_1_id, r1_price.price_normal AS room_1_price, SUM(r1_price.price_normal) as room_1_total,
       room_2_id,r2_price.price_normal AS room_2_price,SUM(r2_price.price_normal) as room_2_total,
       omc_hotel_season_period.date
FROM (SELECT r1.hotel_id, r1.id AS room_1_id, r2.id AS room_2_id FROM omc_hotel_room r1
      INNER JOIN omc_hotel_room r2 ON r1.hotel_id = r2.hotel_id
      WHERE r1.quantity >= 3 AND r2.quantity >= 4 AND r1.pax_max = 1 AND r2.pax_max = 2) AS candidates
LEFT JOIN omc_hotel_season_period
          ON candidates.hotel_id = omc_hotel_season_period.hotel_id
             AND date BETWEEN '2013-08-13' AND '2013-08-15'
             AND omc_hotel_season_period.date <> 0
LEFT JOIN omc_hotel_room_pricelist r1_price
          ON (candidates.hotel_id = r1_price.hotel_id
              AND room_1_id= r1_price.room_type_id)
LEFT JOIN omc_hotel_room_pricelist r2_price
          ON (candidates.hotel_id = r2_price.hotel_id
              AND room_1_id = r2_price.room_type_id)
WHERE
    r1_price.season_id =  omc_hotel_season_period.season_id
    AND
    r2_price.season_id =  omc_hotel_season_period.season_id
GROUP BY candidates.hotel_id, omc_hotel_season_period.date
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: That's funny. I'm actually working on a hotel reservation form for our hotel right now. Have you thought about varying the rates based on the number of people?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see if this is what u want.

```
SELECT candidates.hotel_id, omc_hotel_season_period.season_id,
   room_1_id, r1_price.price_normal AS room_1_price, SUM(r1_price.price_normal) as room_1_total,
   room_2_id,r2_price.price_normal AS room_2_price,SUM(r2_price.price_normal) as room_2_total,
   omc_hotel_season_period.date,
   (SELECT SUM(room1_price.price_normal)
    FROM omc_hotel_room_pricelist room1_price
    INNER JOIN omc_hotel_room room1 ON room1_price.hotel_id = room1.hotel_id
    INNER JOIN omc_hotel_season_period so1 ON room1_price.hotel_id = so1.hotel_id AND room1_price.season_id = so1.season_id
    INNER JOIN omc_hotel hotel1 ON room1_price.hotel_id = hotel1.id
    WHERE
       so1.date BETWEEN '2013-08-13' AND '2013-08-15' AND
       room1.quantity >= 3 AND room1.pax_max = 1 AND
       hotel1.id = candidates.hotel_id 
    GROUP BY candidates.hotel_id
   ) AS room_1_sum
FROM (SELECT r1.hotel_id, r1.id AS room_1_id, r2.id AS room_2_id FROM omc_hotel_room r1
  INNER JOIN omc_hotel_room r2 ON r1.hotel_id = r2.hotel_id
  WHERE r1.quantity >= 3 AND r2.quantity >= 4 AND r1.pax_max = 1 AND r2.pax_max = 2) AS    candidates
LEFT JOIN omc_hotel_season_period
      ON candidates.hotel_id = omc_hotel_season_period.hotel_id
         AND date BETWEEN '2013-08-13' AND '2013-08-15'
         AND omc_hotel_season_period.date <> 0
LEFT JOIN omc_hotel_room_pricelist r1_price
      ON (candidates.hotel_id = r1_price.hotel_id
          AND room_1_id= r1_price.room_type_id)
LEFT JOIN omc_hotel_room_pricelist r2_price
      ON (candidates.hotel_id = r2_price.hotel_id
          AND room_1_id = r2_price.room_type_id)
WHERE
r1_price.season_id =  omc_hotel_season_period.season_id
AND
r2_price.season_id =  omc_hotel_season_period.season_id
GROUP BY candidates.hotel_id
```

Comment: whats the answer you are expecting for say hotel id 1

Comment: If you just need total price,why do u group by on date too?

Comment: Because some dates having different prices for the same room which are assigned by different season. For Example.. IF you say.. on 13-08-2013, one room is assigned to high season and on another day the same room is assigned to low season.. depending on different dates.